# Just entered a new arena, what about the free chests?

Tags: clash-royale

I was thinking, I just came to a new arena with great difficulty. I believe that when I start playing again I will lose 50 trophies and return to the previous arena. Theoretically, I can stop battling and get cards from the new arena through free chests, right?

I mean, it does not say anywhere I look that this is impossible. But it seems like this is an appeal that people can abuse a lot (for example, your skills, cards level and deck are not worthy of the next arena but you can get as many cards as you want from there due to an event of luck). But the thing is: I've been in this situation before and never got cards of the new arena from free chests after I only won the battle to get to this new arena.

So, it begs the question: **Is there anything programmed in the game to just give cards of the new arena after some victories in it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Yes you can. I'm in goblin arena and I didn't play for a while to unlock the cards before risking a loss and leaving goblin arena. So yeah just wait and chill play some tournaments or classic challenges while you wait. 
Plus if you play a classic or a grand challenge you still get crowns from wins getting the crown chest without losing any trophies.

Answer (score 1):

http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Chests

You can read all about the chests here.

For the "**Is there anything programmed in the game to just give cards of the new arena after some victories in it?**" part of your question, there doesn't seem to be anything like that so you probably should get cards of the arena from the Free chests as well.